# CSS - Expand button width smoothly and display text on hover

Tags: html, css

I was trying to make a button animation on hover states where initial state the button will show with an icon only and after hover on it will expand the width and then display the text inside of it.

I can't add predefined max-width or width or width value as I don't know what would be the length of the text as is rendered from a back end service

I had added some CSS code on it but it's not working properly.
The flow what I need like  -

1. Initial state display button with icon
2. After hovering the width of the button will expand up to the text length
3. Then show the text inside the button

```css
.sti_container{
  position: relative;
}

.btn{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}
.btn .btn-text{
  width: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: color 2s;
  transition: color 2s;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: blue;
}
.btn:hover .btn-text{
  width: auto;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="sti_container">
  <button class="btn">
    <span class="btn-icon"><i class="fa fa-shopping-bag" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    <span class="btn-text">Shop the image here to click and open</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Width `auto` values can't be animated, so use `max-width` instead:

```css
.sti_container {
  position: relative;
}

.btn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}

.btn .btn-text {
  max-width: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: color .25s 1.5s, max-width 2s;
  transition: color .25s 1.5s, max-width 2s;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: blue;
}

.btn:hover .btn-text {
  max-width: 300px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="sti_container">
  <button class="btn">
    <span class="btn-icon"><i class="fa fa-shopping-bag" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    <span class="btn-text">Shop the image here to click and open</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

The other problem is that you animating only color, so you need to change your transition property to `transition: color 2s, max-width 2s;`

Comment: I can't add predefined max-width or width value as I don't know what would be the  length of the text as is rendered from a back end service

Comment: You can add `max-width: 99999px` if you want to, you won't have text longer than that length :)

Comment: Also, still, your animation does not work properly. The first button will expand with no text display and after expand the text will display.

Comment: Not sure I understand you correctly. If I am correct, you want to delay your color transition `transition: color 2s 2s, max-width 2s;`

Comment: Yes, i wanted to delay the color of the text.

Comment: Updated the answer to include delay.